# Exporting a pandas dataframe and the bar chart to the same html or pdf file (prefered that the pdf or html has only one page)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a pandas dataframe and also plotted the graph using data_frame.plot.bar(). I want to export the dataframe and the graph into the same html or pdf file (any one of the two is fine). I want to do this only using matplotlib and pandas as I do not want to make end user of the program install any additional libraries just for this task (such as mpld3 or plotly).

I have attached the code I have written so far below.

Is it possible to create a pdf or html file only using pandas and matplotlib?

I will really appreciate help with this.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



# expecting the input in the form of dictionary containing the row names and data in the rows
dictionary = {'C': [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000], 'V': [0.0000, 0.3940, 0.0000],
              'S': [0.0000, 0.0660, 0.0000], 'I': [94.3160, 0.0000, 0.0000],
              'D': [0.0000, 6.7720, 7.4920], 'CV': [5.6410, 0.0000, 6.5660],
              'ID': [0.0080, 52.2240, 85.3500]}

data_frame = df.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index', columns=['CP1', 'C2', 'C3'])

plot = data_frame.plot.bar(title='Percentage  use ', stacked=True)
plot.set_xlabel('name')
plot.set_ylabel('usage in percentage')
plt.show()
```

Comment: My idea is you can write the html file with the standard "with open(file.html) and include the image either as png or svg. If you want everything into the same file you could save the plot as svg first, then open and copy the code directly to the html

Comment: @Ricardo this seems like a good solution at first. But this is simply not feasible when I have a lot of dataframes and consequently equal number of images. This will mean saving all those images on my client's local drive. Is there any way to avoid saving the images? I am trying something with bytesIO in python. But I am not sure how it works.

Comment: @Ricardo I used your idea and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it working. For completeness I suggest you answer your own question in case anyone else ever comes across this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in order to attach image in a webpage or pdf, it needs to be stored somewhere on the local drive. Hence the solution suggested in the first comment by @Ricardo is the best. I ended up doing the same thing in my program.